# How to Reverse an array in groups in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to reverse the array in groups but I am getting this error:

```
:----  for i in arr: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.
```

What's wrong with my code?

```
   def reverseSubarray(arr,n,k):
      if k == 1:
        return
      i = 0
      while i < n:
        l = i
        r = min(i+k-1, n-1)
        while l < r:
          temp = arr[l]
          arr[l] = arr[r]
          arr[r] = temp
          l += 1
          r -= 1
        i += k
      return arr
    
    def main():
        n = int(input().strip())
        string  = input().strip().split()
        arr=[]
        for j in string:
            arr.append(int(j.strip()))
        k=int(input().strip())
        arr = reverseSubarray(arr,n,k)
        for i in arr:
            print(i,end=' ')
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Can you show example input and desired output?

Comment: You have a plain `return` without value near the top. By default, that returns `None`, which is likely the cause of your error.

Comment: "Reverse an array in groups" is not a very clear problem statement. Your code is full of single letter variable names, so that doesn't help us to understand your intent either. It is literally impossible to help you until you refactor your code into something readable, and actually state your problem with example inputs and output.

Comment: It seems that you `input` `1` here `k=int(input().strip())` which causes `reverseSubarray` to implicitly `return` `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that you're actually returning `None`. This happens because most likely you're giving `k=1` so it will go to that line where you return nothing, which will return this error when trying to iterate.

You can treat the problem with a `try-catch` block on `arr=reverseSubarray(arr,n,k)` that will return a message like `k cannot be 1`

Comment: Oh, Okay , now I got it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse an array in groups in python as given below,

```
def reverseSubarray(arr, N, K):
    for i in range(0, len(arr),K):
        l=arr[i:i+K]
        l.reverse()
        arr[i:i+K] =l
    return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

While your error was indeed coming from the fact that your function is returning `None` as other answers have pointed out, you have also written the function in a very non-pythonic style. Here is an example of how you could rewrite it more succintly:

```py
def reverseInGroups(self, arr, N, K):
    for i in range(0, N, K):
        arr[i:i+K] = reversed(arr[i:i+K])
    return arr
```

- `range(0, N, K)` will return an iterator that goes from 0 to N-1 in steps of K. In other word, `i` will successively have value: 0, K, 2K, 3K, 4K, etc. until the last multiple of K that is less than N. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#range) for more details.
- `arr[i:i+K]` will refer to the [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) of `arr` between indices `i` and `i+K-1` or, put another way, `[arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2], ..., arr[i+K-1]]`. It stops at `i+K-1` so that you can naturally use `arr[i:i+K]` and `arr[i+K:]` without counting `arr[i+K]` twice.
- `reversed`... reverses an iterator. [Here's the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed).